# Как в Visual Studio 2010 создать установщик с пятью RadioButtons

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windowsinstaller

Мне необходимо создать установщик для своего приложения. В нём должна быть форма с пятью RadioButton`ами. Создал проект установщика, далее нажимаю на него ПКМ -> Вид -> пользовательский интерфейс -> добавить диалоговое окно и вот тут я понимаю, что на выбор мне предлагается окно с максимум 4 пунктами выбора. И никакого явного способа добавить в него ещё один я не вижу. Как создать окно с пятью вариантами выбора?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответили здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271460/how-to-create-an-installer-with-no-standard-form-in-the-visual-studio-2010/61340149#61340149

Продублирую, пожалуй: 
Для начала вам нужен архив [customdialogsvsd_src](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18834/Create-custom-dialogs-for-use-in-your-Visual-Studi)
Из него нужно взять файл

```
customdialogsvsd_src/VsdDialogs/0/MMCustom5ButtonDlg.wid
```

и скопировать его в

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\Deployment\VsdDialogs\0
```

Затем нужно файл

```
customdialogsvsd_src\VsdDialogs\1033\MMCustom5ButtonDlg.wid
```

скопировать в

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\Deployment\VsdDialogs\1033
```

Перезапустите студию (как я понял, лучше с правами администратора). Всё, теперь в установщике можно делать форму с пятью радио кнопками.

Важный момент! Этот способ не сработает, если студия у вас локализованная!